# At a high level, how does python generate and assign ID values to objects?

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory-management

I've started learning Python by digging through the standard library and I came across the id() function. After spending some time tinkering with the function, I became curious to know how the interpreter divvies these values out, or even how they are generated. Is this value related to the memory address? There is the note **CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in memory.** in the documentation, but that I'm assuming that doesn't hold true for other implementations based on the existence of that note.

Comment: Did you check the documentation for the other implementations yet?

Comment: Each implementation can do whatever it wants, so nothing can be said in general. You answered your question regarding CPython.

Comment: Is there any implementation that you are particularly curious about?

Comment: I suppose, for instance, if I wanted to work with Jython, that documentation too states it is the memory address. Are each of the implementations generally leveraging their base code to communicate the memory address? I guess my question could be rephrased out of curiosity how at a high level the python standard library uses C, or JVM in Jythons case

Comment: The memory address is ideal as an ID because it's A) guaranteed to be unique, B) easy to access, C) space efficient - the object itself doesn't need to store it. It's hard to think of a better way.